# APK doesn't install on Cruz after an update, but does on an EVO

Tags: android, installation, apk

A while ago I wrote an app and I was able to install it both on an EVO phone and a Cruz tablet.  I got the app to the EVO via email to a gmail account, and to the Cruz via USB download.

I recently made some changes to the app, again emailed the EVO and downloaded to the Cruz via USB.  The EVO got the app and was able to install, but when I try to install on the Cruz (through Astro's Open App Manager), in the details I get a message saying 'Could not open /sdcard/download/ETA.apk as APK file.  In the summary tab, there is no info, such as Name, lable, file version, etc.  I've signed and zipaligned this apk like it's my job and the fact that it works on the EVO has got me flabbergasted.  I've since tried going back to the original version, but I have the same issue.

Am I missing something?

Comment: You mean that the original also does not install?

Comment: Right.  It did install when I first tried it.  Then I did some dinking around and tried installing that version, which I saved to a different location.  After that didn't work, I tried reverting back to the old version, then that one didn't install either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that I had apparently NOT saved the original APK file.  I built the APK using decreasing Platform/API levels until I got down to 1.6.  I guess the Cruz is Android 2.0 (which I don't have ??).  I didn't have to change any code; I did however have to change the manifest a bit (android:minSdkVersion="4").

After that it installs just fine.

Comment: Is there something I need to do other then click the check box?